# Check past state of a boolean in python

Tags: python

Is it possible for me to check the state of a boolean (or var doesn't matter) as it was before i changed it. Basically i want it to work like this: if boolean is true and was false - do action. I'm a bit new so sorry if this question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: store previous value in temp, check if temp == current value. That should work. Isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep a second variable for that and assign it with the current one as you modify the current one:

```
prevA, A = A, newValue()
if A and not prevA:
   ...
```